# How to run python script in command line

Tags: python, linux

I want to run a python script which is located in "path=/home/user/code" in another python code by os.system, in linux. I run the following code and it runs well:

```
os.system("cd "+path+ ";" + "./update.py")
```

But I want to run the script without changing the current directory. So when I run the following code:

```
os.system("."+path + "/update.py")
```

I get an error that says: "./home/user/code/update.py not found"

How can I solve it?

Comment: Remove the leading period. That's not a valid path.

Comment: provide just the absolute path, instead of making it relative. Get rid of the `"."`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to correct it:

```
os.system(path + "/update.py")
```

so basically it will be like - `os.system(/home/user/code/update.py)`

Answer (score 1):

Remove the "." at the start of the command.

By typing "./home/..." you are asking Python to search for a folder called "home" in the current directory. If you remove the ".", the path will be interpreted as absolute and it should work. You might also have to provide the `python` keyword at the start of your command. So your final command will be:

```
python /home/user/code/update.py
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run Python script in `windows` using CMD. Just use `py` to run it

```
py myfile.py
```

or

```
python myfile.py
```

It works very well in Windows CMD/PowerShell.

**NOTE:** make sure to run cmd on that directory where the Python script is available. Otherwise, you have to put a complete path.